# Cannot call value of non-function type UIAlertAction

Tags: swift

I'm not sure what's wrong with this function.  I'm trying to present an alert asking if the user would like to delete the selected photo.

If the function that deletes the photo returns an error, I would like to show that error to the user.

Xcode is failing on the errorController.addAction line with the message that "cannot call value of non-function type UIAlertAction"

I'm using Swift 2

```
@IBAction func deletePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Delete Photo", message: "Are you sure you want to delete this photo?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { UIAlertAction in

        self.photoGateway!.delete(self.photo!.id!, completion: { (withError: Bool) -> Void in

            if (withError == true) {
                let errorController = UIAlertController(title: "Delete Failed", message: "blah", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                //  The next line is causing the error
                errorController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(errorController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            }

        })

    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { UIAlertAction in
        print("Cancelled")
    }

    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

If I take out the offending line then all works well, just the user has no way of dismissing the alert

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Fixed it. Changed:

```
errorController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
```

to:

```
errorController.addAction(UIKit.UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
```

Comment: Cool, it works... but... why do we even need to do this? It works without the scope prefix throughout my code in countless places, except in one particular place.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I would also like to know why this makes the difference in the context of being within a handler when not required outside of one.

Comment: For me, this worked `alertMode.addAction(UIKit.UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))`

Answer (score 3):

The reason this is happening is because the parameter for your callbacks is called `UIAlertAction` (lines 3 and 20 above) and this is overriding the declaration in UIKit. This is likely a mistake of code-completion. Just rename it to `action` or something like that or just `_` as you don't reference it.